# Grouping identical rows and returning the id of the row with a maximum value

Tags: vb.net, linq, grouping

I have a datatable like below:

```
id  desc    amt  value 1  value 2  value 3  value 4  count  Consolidated ID

1   test    23   78       98       30       13       5  
2   sample  14   25       45       36       12       24 
3   test    23   78       98       30       13       30 
4   sample  14   25       45       36       12       20 
5   test    23   78       98       30       13       11
```

I need to

1. group by the columns `desc`, `amt`, `value1`, `value2`, `value3` and `value4`, and
2. return the `consolidated ID` as the `id` which has maximum in the `count` column for each group. Result set should be like below:

   ```
    id  desc   amt  value 1  value 2  value 3  value 4  count  Consolidated ID

    1   test   23   78       98       30       13       5      3
    3   test   23   78       98       30       13       30     3
    5   test   23   78       98       30       13       11     3
    2   sample 14   25       45       36       12       24     2
    4   sample 14   25       45       36       12       20     2
   ```

I know this can be done looping through datatable. But is there a simpler way to do it with LINQ in 1 or 2 statements?

Comment: Do you want to return the results in a new LINQ query? Or do you want to fill the `consolidated id` column in the original datatable?

Comment: Linq query below in C# produce the exact result, but you may certainly need a code converter for VB.Net

Answer (score 2):

```
DataTable - dt
```

Result will be of type `IEnumerable` of anonymous type in the `Select` statement, which has same columns as your `DataTable`

```
var final = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x=>
                                      new {
                                            amt = x["amt"],
                                            value1 = x["value1"],
                                            value2 = x["value2"],
                                            value3 = x["value3"],
                                            value4 = x["value4"],                                              
                                         })
                          .ToDictionary(p=>p.Key,
                                        p=>new {id = p.Select(s=>s["id"]),
                                                cid = p.OrderByDescending(n=>Convert.ToInt32((n["count"]))).Select(s=>s["id"]).First()})
                          .SelectMany(a=>a.Value.id.Select(h=>new { 
                                    h,
                                    a.Key.amt,
                                   a.Key.value1,
                                   a.Key.value2,
                                   a.Key.value3,
                                   a.Key.value4,                                       
                                   ConsolidatedID = a.Value.cid
                                }));
```

Also pasting the VB.Net version (using Telerik Code Converter) as that has been the point of contention, though needs verification, as I do not work in VB.Net

```
Dim final = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(x) New With { _
    Key .amt = x("amt"), _
    Key .value1 = x("value1"), _
    Key .value2 = x("value2"), _
    Key .value3 = x("value3"), _
    Key .value4 = x("value4") _
}).ToDictionary(Function(p) p.Key, Function(p) New With { _
    Key .id = p.[Select](Function(s) s("id")), _
    Key .cid = p.OrderByDescending(Function(n) Convert.ToInt32((n("count")))).[Select](Function(s) s("id")).First() _
}).SelectMany(Function(a) a.Value.id.[Select](Function(h) New With { _
    h, _
    a.Key.amt, _
    a.Key.value1, _
    a.Key.value2, _
    a.Key.value3, _
    a.Key.value4, _
    Key .ConsolidatedID = a.Value.cid _
}))
```

Comment: OP needs a Vb.net solution.

Comment: Irrespective of what your argument is, this solution doesn't help the OP. A better way for ***not doing spoon feeding*** would be to just give a solution leading him into the right direction without posting any code. A code snippet in another language helps no one, since they may or may not be familiar with that language. If you edit your answer and post the vb.net version, I will remove the downvote.

Comment: Also I am not posting any solution because I am logged in from my mobile and nowhere near a PC to test my solution. Better to not post a solution rather than posting a non-working /untested solution which helps noone.

Comment: Thats good if you don't want to change your attitude and want to continue getting downvoted. Also I sledom downvote anyone and never without a reason, since I lose points too.

Comment: @ Zev Spitz, I need to test that, My LinqPad version is a custom entity, which works fine as expected. but i think you are right in this case. I will modify the solution. Thanks for the good catch :)

Comment: @ Zev Spitz Modified please check now, this works fine on my local machine, now I have an indexer based access instead of property

Comment: @MrinalKamboj  it looks alright; if you tested it I'll leave the OP to figure out if it satisfies his question. However, I highly recommend that you go back and delete any unnecessary comments (including your responses to mine).

Comment: @ Zev Spitz, yes with current data provided it produce the correct result as expected by OP

Comment: @MrinalKamboj There is far too much noise in the comments here.

Comment: @PradeepKumar There is far too much noise in the comments here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the `consolidated id` column in the datatable, I suggest you first define a local function that returns the "key" of the row -- the values important to grouping:

```
Dim keyGetter = Function(row As DataRow) New With {
        Key .desc = row("desc"), 
        Key .amt = row("amt"), 
        Key .value1 = row("value 1"), 
        Key .value2 = row("value 2"), 
        Key .value3 = row("value 3"), 
        Key .value4 = row("value 4")
}
```

Then, for each group, you can get the `id` of the row with the maximum `count`:

```
Dim results = dt.AsEnumerable.GroupBy(keyGetter, Function(key, grp)
        Dim maxCount = grp.Max(Function(row) x("count"))
        Return grp.First(Function(row) row("count") = maxCount)
    End Function).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(x) x.First)
```

Then you can iterate over the datatable and fill the column. For each row, generate the key using the `keyGetter`, and use that to get the `consolidated id`:

```
For Each row In dt.AsEnumerable
    row("consolidated id") = results(keyGetter(row))
Next
```